# Google Map Printing Icon Issue

Tags: google-maps

I have made a custom made map using Google maps, and have saved multiple places to my map with different colored pins, depending on what each house is available for that day. When I go to print out the map to distribute to people, all of my different types and colors of pins revert to the standard format. They do not do this until I hit print preview. Does anyone know of a way that I can fix this?

Comment: could you augment your answer? What programming language would this be? This site is for programming questions only, so people get nervous if no programming language or framework is mentioned.